# Convert short name in complete names

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> ListaClientes = new List<string>();
ListaClientes.Add("CERTIFIC ENERGÉT");
ListaClientes.Add("EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL");
```

I have one textbox (`TextBox1`) that reads a Excel cell. I have another textbox (`TextBox2`) that I want to display the *long name* in the list.
For example, if `TextBox1` display `CE`, it must display on `TextBox2` `CERTIFIC ENERGÉT`. If `TextBox1` display `EI`, it must display on `TextBox2` `EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL`

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the Dictionary<> generic class? You can use it to map one string to another by having a Dictionary<string, string> containing the mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` achieve what you're after:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("CE", "CERTIFIC ENERGÉT");
...
```

Then to assign the value to Textbox2 you can do:

```
Textbox2.Text = dict[Textbox1.Text];
```

I've not done any error checking so if a key doesn't exist in the dictionary then you'll get an exception thrown so you will need to handle that 
accordingly.

Further reading **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)**

Answer (score 2):

For a given `List<string>`

```
  List<string> ListaClientes = new List<string>() {
    "CERTIFIC ENERGÉT",
    "EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL",
  };
```

Let's build a `Dictionary<string, string>` where `Key` is a user input (`TextBox1.Text`), say `"CE"` and `Value` is a corresponding text `"CERTIFIC ENERGÉT"`:

```
 {
   {"CE", "CERTIFIC ENERGÉT"},
   {"EI", "EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL"},
 }
```

If you want *abbreviations* as keys, you can use *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  // Extracts all capital letters from each word
  Func<string, string> abbreviation = (value) => string.Concat(Regex
    .Matches(value, @"\b\p{Lu}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value));

  Dictionary<string, string> dict = ListaClientes
    .GroupBy(item => abbreviation(item), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                  group => group.First(), // In case of conflict, use 1st text
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

then, you can easily map:

```
 TextBox2.Text = dict.TryGetValue(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), out var text) 
   ? text            // we have a corresponding text
   : TextBox1.Text;  // we don't have corresponding text, let's repeat TextBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if textbox1 display CE, it must display on textbox2 CERTIFIC ENERGÉT. 
>   If textbox1 display EI, it must display on textbox2 EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL

You can do something like this

```
var ListaClientes = new List<string>
{
    "CERTIFIC ENERGÉT",
    "EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL"
};

var ce = ListaClientes[0];
string shortcut = "";
ce.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => shortcut += i[0]);

textBox1.Text = shortcut;
textBox2.Text = ce;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say thank you to all the help.

I will try to explain what I need:
I have two textboxs - One that reads data from datagridview (textbox8Cod) and another that must show long name description (textBox7Serv).
For example, if textBox8Cod display EDMO, it must display on textBox7Serv, CERTIFICAÇÃO ENERGÉTICA

This is a DataGridView event:

```
private void DataGridViewNE_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridViewNE.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
        //Reads data:
        dataGridViewNE.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
        textBox8Cod.Text = dataGridViewNE.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["F8"].FormattedValue.ToString();

        //Translate codes
        var ListaClientes = new List<string>
    {"CERTIFICAÇÃO ENERGÉTICA","EDIFÍCIO INDUSTRIAL OU ARMAZÉM"};
        var ce = ListaClientes[0];
        string shortcut = "";
        ce.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => shortcut += i[0]);
        textBox8Cod.Text = shortcut;
        textBox7Serv.Text = ce;
    }
```

I try the last solution, but it do not work. Thank you.